# Does Cocoa’s printf-style formatting not work as expected when using %@ conversion specifier and field width?

Tags: cocoa, printf, string-formatting

My understanding of printf-like format strings is that you can prefix any conversion specifier with a minimum field width. This does not seem to work for Cocoa’s `%@` specifier.
Example:

```
NSLog(@"'%5@'", @"foo");
NSLog(@"'%5s'", [@"foo" UTF8String]);
```

Output:

```
… 'foo'
… '  foo'
```

Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: I'd report it as a bug: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Done: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=213401

Answer (score 1):

%@ is only for objective-c object. Thus, the field width will be invalid, if the object is not NSString.

I didn't know that %5@ is formatted to be the same as %@.

Comment: Cocoa’s formatting function always calls `descriptionWithLocale:` (or `description`) on the object to get a string representation. This string representation could be padded to a given field width.

Answer (score 0):

The %@ format specifier just gets replaced by the object's description. It doesn't do any truncation or padding.

Comment: Exactly. Don't you think that's wrong behavior? Or did you mean there's documentation which defines it to behave different to other format specifiers?

Comment: @Nikolai: I make no value judgement over whether it's correct or not, I just said that's how it worked :).